# Remove pandas columns based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
```

and a pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [1, 2], 'd': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What can I do to remove the columns in `df` based on list `my_list`, in this case remove columns `a` and `b`

Comment: `df.drop(my_list,1)` use `df.drop`

Comment: Please read the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
df = df.drop(columns=my_list)
```

`drop` removes columns by specifying a list of column names

Answer (score 0):

This is a concise script using list comprehension: [df.pop(x) for x in my_list]

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [1, 2], 'd': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.to_markdown())
|    |   a |   b |   c |   d |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   3 |   1 |   3 |
|  1 |   2 |   4 |   2 |   4 |

[df.pop(x) for x in my_list]
print(df.to_markdown())
|    |   c |   d |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   3 |
|  1 |   2 |   4 |
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select required columns as well:

```
cols_of_interest = ['c', 'd']
df = df[cols_of_interest]
```

if you have a range of columns to drop: for example 2 to 8, you can use:

```
df.drop(df.iloc[:,2:8].head(0).columns, axis=1)
```